# How to truncate the long task name in the agenda custom view?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In emacs org-mode, I define some org-agenda-custom-commands. But some task names are too long than the screen in the *Org Agenda* buffer.

How to truncate the long task name in the agenda custom view?

Comment: Please provide an example showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The display of the agenda will reflect the setting of Emacs' `truncate-lines` variable. The function `toggle-truncate-lines` is the easiest way to flip this on or off interactively. Org-mode also provides the `org-startup-truncated` variable which will govern what the default value for `truncate-lines` should be throughout org-mode:

```
Non-nil means entering Org-mode will set `truncate-lines'.
This is useful since some lines containing links can be very long and
uninteresting.  Also tables look terrible when wrapped.
```

If you really want to have truncation turned off globally (including in Org-mode buffers) but you want lines in your agenda to wrap then you can add something to `org-agenda-mode-hook` to disable the option:

```
(defun my/org-agenda-mode-hook ()
  (interactive)
  (setq truncate-lines nil))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          'my/org-agenda-mode-hook)
```